# PHP textarea refresh after SQL update and show text

Tags: php

I got a problem with my code. I using a textarea to update my db. When I'm saving the changes, the page refreshes and shows the pre-edited text.

After searching Threads for 2h, it's Time to ask a stupid Question....

I tried with

```
    header('Location: ./kommers_edit.php');
```

it worked, but not in the way I need.

I need to pass my id variable (I use a form now) to get the content and show a message that the text was edited.

I thought about an extrapage, to show edited text and message ... is there a more "elegant", and maybe not complex, way to do this?

```php
    if (isset ($_GET['aktion']))
{
    if ($_GET['aktion'] == "speichern" )
{
    $liedtitel      = $_GET['liedtitel'];
    $liedtext       = $_GET['liedtext'];
    $id             = $_GET['id'];

    $liedtitel_html= nl2br ($liedtitel,true);
    $liedtext_html= nl2br ($liedtext,true);

    $sql  = "UPDATE kommersbuch SET liedtitel='$liedtitel_html',liedtext='$liedtext_html' WHERE id='$id'";

    require_once ('config.php');
    $db_data = mysql_query($sql)
    or die("Anfrage fehlgeschlagen: " . mysql_error());

    echo '<h2>Lied wurde geändert</h2>';
    echo '<a href="kommers.php">zurück zum Kommersbuch</a>';
    //header('Location: ./kommers_edit.php');    
    exit;
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a form, which posts to the same page as the form the form data. If the page catches the form post, it updates the form in the database.

As this is an update, can I assume that this entry already exists?

So I imagine you have a select in place to populate the form data prior to the submission? Just make sure to run that again after the update. The ID doesn't change.

Roughly:

```
<?php
if($_POST['action'] = "submission"){
    $sql = "UPDATE...."
    $r = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    // do your request & validtion, make sure it works.
}
$sql = "SELECT * ...."
$r = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
// Do your request & validation, make sure it worked

?>
<form action ="" method="POST">
   <input value="<?php echo $result['colname'];?> name="colname">
   <textarea name="textname"><?php echo $result['textname']; ?></textarea>
   <input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit">
   <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

This way, the select that would populate the form in the first place will repopulate it with what just went into the database.

Now if you want to, in the case of a validation error, populate the fields with what was sent (but is not in the database), just assign the sent values to $request['sentvaluename'] and stop the SELECT query from happening.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

try use

```
header('Location: ./kommers_edit.php?id=$id');
```

after that,
in the kommers_edit.php, make a script that get the id